# antd v4 custom Form validation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm in the process of updating things to antd v4, and using the [migration guide for forms](https://ant.design/components/form/v3) I'm not seeing how to handle custom validators.  Before these were in the rules from `getFieldDecorator` but now we should be able to move away from that.  Code example is below (tried to leave in enough to remove mystery), and what I'm seeing is that in my validator function, `validatePassword`, I'm not getting a value.  So I'm guessing that I'm missing something easy on how to now pass the form item value to the validator, but I'm not seeing it in the documentation.  Any ideas?

```
import * as React from 'react';
...
import { Form, Input } from 'antd';
...

/** Presentational */
import FormWrapper from '../../Components/Styled/FormWrapper';

...

const passwordValidator = require('password-validator');

// create a password schema
const schema = new passwordValidator();

schema
  .is().min(8)
  .has().uppercase()
  .has().lowercase()
  .has().digits()
  .has().symbols();

class SignUpContainer extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  ...

  validatePassword = (rule: object, val: string, callback: (message?: string) => void) => {
    console.log(val);               // <-- This says val is undefined
    const form = this.props.form;
    const validationRulesErrors = schema.validate(val, { list: true });

    if (val && this.state.confirmDirty) {
      form.validateFields(['confirm'], { force: true });
    }
    if (validationRulesErrors.length > 0) {
      callback(this.formatPasswordValidateError(validationRulesErrors));
    }
    callback();
  };

  formatPasswordValidateError = (errors: Array<string>) => {
    ...
  };

  render() {
    ...
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <FormWrapper onFinish={this.handleSubmit}>
          ...
          <Form.Item 
            name='password'
            rules={
              [
                { required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' },
                {
                  validator: this.validatePassword
                }
              ]
            }
          >
            <Input
              prefix={<LockOutlined style={{ color: colors.transparentBlack }} />}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          </Form.Item>
          ...
        </FormWrapper>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUpContainer;
```

Comment: Your validator callback should return a promise. You can refer to [this example](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register) on how they built a custom validator.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Thanks!  I somehow missed that switch to returning promise from passing/returning a callback.  If you want to write it up as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.